# How can I enable step-by-step debugging in phpstorm?

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm

I configured phpstorm for debugging by xdebug but Just I can use debug and select one of page to simple debug.**I checked all the settings steps of jetbrains.com that were done correctly But The step by step debug buttons is disabled Yet, such as stepOver and step intro and else...**

**How can I enable step-by-step debugging in phpstorm?**

In addition, after debugging the codes, the error :   *PHP Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '.\dref.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\srn\mrt\req_v.php on line 260*
  is displayed, while the same code works well in the wamp by Firefox

Then when I change path ".\dref.php" in require_once to "..\dref.php" debugging dont display above warning But in wamp when open web by Firefox display *Warning: require_once(..\dref.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\srn\mrt\req_v.php on line 261*

**Waht Shoul I do to solve this problem?**

Comment: You would need to add some more info about your setup here. What link exactly are you using to debug? It looks like you're debugging using built-in web server (localhost:64431) while you want to debug using your wamp installation (localhost:80). You would need to set up a correct deployment server for this (seems like inplace would suit here). A starting page for this is https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/